# SayDigits Not Working in Asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk, centos7, pbx, freepbx

The issue is ***`SayDigits`***  is showing the files that are being played in the debug but cannot hear any sounds as shown below

```
Executing [*30@processor:1] SayDigits("SIP/507-0000000a", "507") in new stack
--`<SIP/507-0000000a> Playing 'digits/5.gsm' (language 'en')` 
--`<SIP/507-0000000a> Playing 'digits/0.gsm' (language 'en')`
--`<SIP/507-0000000a> Playing 'digits/7.gsm' (language 'en')`
```

have anybody faced this issue? How do I solve it?

Comment: did you Answer() the call first?

Answer (score 2):

You need to answer the call first:

```
[processor]
exten => *30,1,Answer()
 same => n,SayDigits(${EXTEN})
 ...
```

*this syntax considers you are using a recent version of Asterisk.

Comment: Also need ensure you really have sound files.

Comment: There is no output that would suggest that the server does not have the required sounds.